# Activity Indicator and Cancel button

Tags: ios

When I tap button app create network request. I want to show activity indicator and I want have possibility of stop this request, so I want cancel button. I can add activity indicator to alert view, but Apple say "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."
What is the right UI for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom `UIView` for this situation. 
You use `UIAlertController` for alerts. doesn't seems right to make a network request there.
Put your button on your custom view, start the activity indicator animation and make the request.